# Android wear stream accelerometer data to handheld

Tags: android, android-wear-data-api

I an new to android wear app  development. I wanted to create an app which streams accelerometer data continuously from wear device to handheld, and do some processing on my handheld. Does anyone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I went through that pain recently. Try this link (a lot of base code required)

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html up to the syncing data items page

Essentially, the data-api makes a shared dictionary that fires an event when a field is updated. Unfortunately the bluetooth connectivity seems quite slow. My current workaround is to increase the sensor delay and only update if the change is fairly dramatic.